# Symfony2 form builder entity (not mapped) setting value (data) not working

Tags: symfony, default-value, formbuilder

I have problem in form builder while setting default value, I crate not mapped list and I want to set default value like this:

```
        ->add('kuponaiSuppliers', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'CMSBundle:KuponaiUsers',
            'label'=> "Supplier:",
            'data'=>5,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('ku')
                        ->select("ku")
                        ->andWhere("ku.delDate is null")
                        ->andWhere("ku.id > 1");
                },
            'property'=> 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'mapped' => false
        ))
```

But all I get in my view it just list without any selected option:

```
<select id="acme_cmsbundle_kuponaimain_kuponaiSuppliers" name="acme_cmsbundle_kuponaimain[kuponaiSuppliers]">
    <option value="2">Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="5">Supplier 2</option>
    <option value="6">Supplier 3</option>
</select>
```

I thought that data attribute have to set default value but it doesn't.

Twig code:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3">{{ form_label(form.kuponaiSuppliers) }}{{ form_widget(form.kuponaiSuppliers) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show us your twig code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the reference of the object you want to be the default.

```
'data' => $this->em->getReference("CMSBundle:KuponaiUsers", 5) // 5 will be the default.
```

`$this->em` points to the entity manager. Could be `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` in a controller.

If you're using a FormType class, you'll have to inject the entity manager. If you're creating the form in a controller, then you can access the entity manager without problem.

The method EntityManager#getReference($entityName, $identifier) lets you obtain a reference to an entity for which the identifier is known, without loading that entity from the database.

Should work.